# Ошибка при .merge() двух DataFrames. Появляется много "лишних" строк

Tags: python, pandas, merge

#два датафрейма df1 и df2, общий столбец course_id, содержит 16 уникальных значений.
#df1 - 300 тыс срок
#df2 - 1200 строк

```
df1 = full_df[['progress_id', 'course_id']]
df2 = course_contents_df[['course_id', 'lesson_token']]
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='course_id', right_on='course_id')
```

при слиянии получается 30 млн строк. откуда? в итоговом фрейме также 16 уникальных значений course_id

```
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 350677 entries, 0 to 350676
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------       --------------   ----- 
 0   progress_id  350677 non-null  object
 1   course_id    350677 non-null  object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 8.0+ MB
```

```
df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1201 entries, 0 to 1200
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------        --------------  ----- 
 0   course_id     1201 non-null   object
 1   lesson_token  1201 non-null   object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 18.9+ KB
```

Дубликатов нет ни в 1, ни во 2 фрейме

Comment: а что пишут `df1.info()` и `df2.info()`?

Comment: вы можете править свой вопрос.

Comment: не совсем понятно. общий столбец содержит 16 уникальных значений, но строк у вас 1200 в одном и 300000 в другом и дубликатов нет?

Comment: идея мерджа в том, чтобы к данным progress_id добавить данные  lesson_token а связывает их course_id,  дубликатов нет в progress_id и  в lesson_token

Comment: Так `course_id` у вас повторяется? Тогда у вас "каждый с каждым" соединение получается внутри группы с одинаковым `course_id`, вот у вас строки и размножаются. Грубо говоря, если в 1-й таблице 100 записей с одним `course_id` и в правой таблице 100 записей с этим `course_id`, то на выходе будет таблица с 100*100 = 10_000 записей с этим `course_id`. Тут всё как в `SQL` работает, если вдруг вам так понятнее будет. И хорошо бы привести пример прямо в вопросе - несколько строк данных из обоих датафреймов и что вы хотели получить на выходе из этих строк.

Comment: Так, а что сделать? как объединить?

Comment: смотря что вы хотите получить. можете сгруппировать по course_id, и потом мержить. но тогда вам нужно задуматься об агрегации других колонок.

Comment: Так вы приведите для начала примеры: что у вас есть и что вы хотите. На куске реальных данных. Пока не очень понятно что тут можно сделать.

Comment: Я все понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я все понял спасибо. в второй таблице `course_id` должен указывать только на один `Lesson_token`, а он указывает на множество, от сюда и множатся данные.
Я смержу по другим данным. спасибо всем!

UPD: Все получилось!